# Adding new entry in menu context menu in gmail and gsheet...?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking for adding a new item in context menu in google Chrome in gmail and gsheet screen.

I would like to purpose to user to look for internal informations about a text part selected in a mail or a sheet with its right click. Informations founded in an internal sheet...

Does someone have any idea please ?

Thanks a lot, have a good day

I look trough internet with many tags but didn't find anyway...

Comment: That's not possible with google apps script.  The closest you can get is Workspace Addons and really that's not even close to what you are asking.

Comment: just select the text and press `ctrl+f`